# put border around table with 4 or more rows (tr) using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

using the DOM I have

```
document.getElementById('table').rows.length > 4
```

To find the the tables.

How would this be done in jquery while also putting a black border around this table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('table').filter(function() {
    return $(this).children('tbody').children('tr').length > 4;
}).css('border', '2px solid black');
```

i.e find all tables, and filter only those which have more than four `tr` inside their `tbody`.

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/YnVck/

If you don't care about the difference between `thead` and `tbody` then the simpler:

```
$('table').filter(function() {
    return this.rows.length > 4;
}).css('border', '2px solid black');
```

from @Felix Kling's comment is simpler.

Comment: Or `return this.rows.length > 4;`

Comment: He's using `getElementById`, not `getElementsByTagName`.

Comment: @vcsjones: It should be easy for the OP adjust the selector to his needs.

Comment: @Felix - are you sure that'll work if `this` is the table rather than its `tbody` ?

Comment: @Alnitak: Yes, it depends on what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
if($('#table tr').length > 4) {
   $('#table').css('border', '1px solid black');
}
```

<strike>Note that the selector in the `if`statement depends on your markup. For example, if your tr's are in a `tbody`, then it becomes `#table tbody tr`.</strike> Felix's comment is correct.

Comment: `tbody` is *always* added to the DOM, even if it is not specified in the HTML. `$('#table tr')` will work fine as it finds all `tr` *descendants*. No need for `tbody` (only if you want to exclude rows in `thead`).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table').each(function() {
    if ($(this).children('tr').length > 4) {
        $(this).css('border', '5px solid #FFF');
    }
}
```

Might work, untested though.

**EDIT**: The other answers look much better. They remind me why I like SO (: